# change visibility of table in latex

Tags: tables, beamer

Suppose i have two tables. I want to replace the top table with another one, keeping the second table constant. How do I do this in one frame? Should the code be like this:

```
 \begin{table}[visibility on=<{2}>]
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
         A & B \\
         \hline
         C & D \\
         \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

But adding `[visibility on=<{2}>]` doesn't seem to do anything. I hope I have made my question clear.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.gates.logic.US,shapes.gates.logic.IEC,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles} %<-added
\usepackage{multirow}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[square]


\begin{document}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    \begin{table}[]
      \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
             A & B \\
             \hline
             C & D \\
             \hline

        \end{tabular}
 \end{table}

\begin{table}[]

        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
             1 & 2 \\
             \hline
             3 & 4 \\
             \hline

        \end{tabular}

    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note that `\centering` is unnecessary, tables are centred by default in beamer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `visible on` (not `visibility on`) trick works with elements of `tikzpicture`s (when one loads `\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}`, as you do). Outside `tikzpicture`s you only need `\only`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.gates.logic.US,shapes.gates.logic.IEC,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles} %<-added
\usepackage{multirow}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[square]


\begin{document}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\only<2>{\begin{table}[]
      \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
             A & B \\
             \hline
             C & D \\
             \hline

        \end{tabular}
 \end{table}}

\begin{table}[]

        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
             1 & 2 \\
             \hline
             3 & 4 \\
             \hline

        \end{tabular}

    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```